# How long can take a auth onCreate trigger to be run

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

In my app, my auth onCreate() trigger creates some RTDB data for each user (uses transaction so it won't overwrite).

So, when the user authenticates, I intend to have a loading until his data appears on the DB.

However, there is the story that a trigger may take hours or days to take effect, and I ain't sure about the cases that it may happen.

Is it safe to the client to wait until the onCreate auth trigger do its DB work? Or should I manually call a CF function to create the essential data?

Comment: Either option is fine.  Choose the one that best meets the needs of your app.

Comment: But what about this trigger taking so long to happen? Only applies to "exceeding" triggers?

Comment: There is no guarantee how lang any function takes, both on create and http trigers. You are always going to have to wait some unknown amount of time. Is time is important to you, you should benchmark your options and pick the best one.

Comment: Hmm... It is hard to benchmark it when it may never happen in my tests to take hours or days for the trigger to happen (and as stated in question, the client will be loading for the data to be created)...

I just found in the RN firebase package the `(await auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential)).additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser`. If true, I could call a CF to have a similar effect of the trigger. However, lets say the app creashes before the CF call, so the trigger could work as backup.

But, this trigger delay still is foggy.

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned that that trigger might not happen.  It is guaranteed to be invoked at least once.  Cloud Functions triggers would be mostly useless if they didn't execute reliably.  Read this: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#execution_guarantees

Comment: I ain't concerned that they might not happen, but that they may take so long to do it so for the first time. I don't want to make the user wait for so long until the trigger happen.

Comment: OK, it sounds like you should still benchmark the performance and pick the one you like the best.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe, go for it!

But if you want more power use this:

```
const runtimeOpts = {
  timeoutSeconds: 300,
  memory: '1GB'
}
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/users')
  .runWith(runtimeOpts)
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
     //
   });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Comment: I don't see how that code suggestion applies here... the user don't directly creates data on RTDB (I don't like making writes on client, I pass almost everything to CF to have a better control over it as it is an app, so the user may take some time to update the app to a newer version)